Dependecies build gradle duplicate
I'm creating a spring boot project with API soap and I'm using two dependencies that have a duplication conflict with each other.
Error log message:
Execution failed for task ':war'.

Entry WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.

I use these dependencies:
implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.3'
implementation 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'

This is my build.gradle file:
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
}

group = 'eu.tecnosoft'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

task run(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'eu.tecnosoft.licensemanager.LicensemanagerApplication'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'war'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20211205'
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.12.3'
    implementation group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk18on', version: '1.78.1'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version: '3.3.3'

    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-api', version: '0.11.5'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-impl', version: '0.11.5'
    implementation group: 'io.jsonwebtoken', name: 'jjwt-jackson', version: '0.11.5'
    implementation group: 'wsdl4j', name: 'wsdl4j', version: '1.6.2'

    implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.3'
    implementation 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

bootWar {
    archiveFileName = 'licensemanager.war'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

I expect to solve the problem by continuing to use both.

Add your build file, generally this comes from the fact that you are working around the features that spring boot already provides, like generating your own fat jar/war.

Remove the bootWar task, you also shouldn't need the apply plugin: 'war' as you already added that plugin.

On a different note I doubt this will even work as Spring BOot 3 is based on JakartaEE 9+, while the included JAX-WS dependencies seem the old ones relying on JavaEE which aren't compatible.

I followed your suggestions but nothing changes

DId you override additional tasks as well?

no, so do I have to add newer versions?

Newer versions of what? The jaxws-api and implementation probably as those aren't compatible with JakartaEE which you are using (judging from the usage of Spring Boot 3). I suspect they are pulling in old incompatible versions of JAXB.

Newer version of JAXB.

Can I not use this dependecies for implementing SOAP API with Spring Boot 3?

No because that is tied to JavaEE while the Spring Boot version used is for JakartaEE... Well not so much the API, but the com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:2.3.3 is. Use something newer like 4.0.3, which should also pull in a newer JAXB version. Another thing you shouldn't be doing is specify versions for the starters, as those are managed by the plugin you are now mixing 3.3.1 and 3.3.3 dependencies.

I try to use version 4.0.3 of com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri but i can't use the packages for a class generated automatically:

this packages: import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;

Because those are JavaEE packages not JakartaEE packages... As stated numerous times before Spring Boot 3 is JakartaEE 9+, you are including libraries which are for JavaEE which aren't compatible... If you must use these libraries you cannot use Spring Boot 3, and need to stick with Spring Boot 2.

ok, Are there any similar libraries for spring boot 3?

I already told you which one to use. Fix the imports afterwards.

I fixed imports with jakarta but the error it's the same:  WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.
Have i to change also this dependecy:  implementation 'javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:2.3.1'?

You have to remove that dependency. The RI will automatically pull in the correct API version

The change is clear to me but despite the change of libraries it does not solve my problem

I strongly suggest you learn the tools you are working with. Use gradle to list the dependencies and figure out which one is pulling in conflicting versions.

look I already told you where my problem is; I'll tell you again, my problem is that jaxb-core-4.0.5.jar is duplicated and I don't know how to handle this situation. Having said that, I advise you not to use this know-it-all tone, thanks

I know what your problem is, I don't know if you posted everything. You are using gradle and with that you can quite easily get a list of dependencies and nested dependencies. You can use that to figure out what is being pulled in. You are a developer I assume you are able to learn to work with the tools you are using.

Now i solve my problem, i have removed the dependecy jaxb but given your experience I don't understand why you didn't notice it right away since I gave it to you the build.gradle

Your build file you posted here didn't contain a jaxb dependency. So not sure what you posted here but apparently not the file you where actually using.

I have removed this dependency: implementation 'com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-ri:4.0.3 because created this conflict of duplication. My file is posted where there is my request
